# Snake in JS establish left-right movement

Tags: javascript, game-physics

Dears, I have started learning programming and picked out Snake as first project. Since I could not find a proper tutorial for beginners I watched the pygame snake tutorial by "thenewboston" on youtube. I tried to copy his steps with JS, and I ended up with following problem. I can move left and right, but once I stared moving left and press afterwards right, there is a bug: its trying to go left AND right same time. I have absolutely no idea, how to tell JS not to continue moving left, when I pressed right after.

Hope you can explain me the problem and suggest a solution. Thanks!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

lead_x = 100;
lead_y = 100;

function draw_it() {
  // background
  ctx.fillStyle = "white"
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // snake head
  ctx.fillStyle = "green"
  ctx.fillRect(lead_x, lead_y, 20 , 20)
}

draw_it();

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    setInterval(function() {
      lead_x -= 10;
      draw_it();
    }, 100);
   } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    setInterval(function() {
      lead_x += 10;
      draw_it();
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is you're using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) which is going to keep repeating the code in it ad infinitum.

```js
console.log('It just keeps going...');
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('and going...');
}, 1000);
```

Instead, I'd suggest using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to control the "heartbeat" of your game then just modify a number whenever the user presses a direction.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var leadX = 160;
var leadY = 120;

var speed = 10;
var xDirection = 1; // Start out going right

function update() {
  // Update the players position
  
  // If xDirection === 1, move to the right
  // if xDirection === -1, move to the left
  leadX += xDirection * speed;
}

function draw() {
  // Clear the screen and draw the player
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fillRect(leadX, leadY, 10, 10);
}

function heartBeat() {
  update();
  draw();
  
  // Call `heartBeat` again in 100ms
  setTimeout(heartBeat, 100);
}
heartBeat();

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
    // Go to the left
    xDirection = -1;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
    // Go to the right
    xDirection = 1;
  }
};
```

```css
html, body {
  background: #222;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 4px auto;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

set intervar keeps running for infinite, you have to kill previous timers when new one is created or just using a single interval like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

lead_x = 100;
lead_y = 100;

function draw_it() {
  // background
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // snake head
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(lead_x, lead_y, 20 , 20);
}

draw_it();

var left_turn = false;
var right_turn = false;

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        left_turn = true;
        right_turn = false;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        right_turn = true;
        right_turn = false;
    }
}


setInterval(function() {
    if (left_turn) {
        lead_x -= 10;
        draw_it();
    } else if (right_turn) {
        lead_x += 10;
        draw_it();
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to ensure that when the left key is pressed, the right key function stops repeating and when the right key is pressed, the left key function stops repeating:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        clearInterval(goRight);

        var goLeft = setInterval(function() {
            lead_x -= 10;
            draw_it();
        }, 100);
    } 

    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        clearInterval(goLeft);

        var goRight = setInterval(function() {
            lead_x += 10;
            draw_it();
        }, 100);
    }
}
```